# SQL, NOT IN within a group

Tags: sql

I have a table T1 with fields f1 and f2 and a table T2 with fields f3 and f4.

Let 's have some dummy values :

```
T1: (1,1) (2,3) (3,3) (4,3) (5,1)
T2: (1,1) (1,2) (3,1) (3,3)
```

We can think of f2 and f3 as defining the same thing, a bridge between T1 and T2. I would like to retrieve every f1 that is not associated with a f4 value of 2 . So my expected output would be :

(2),(3),(4) as at the 1 and 5 F1 value F2=F3=1 has f4=2 on T2.

How can I achieve this ?

Edit 2 : I forgot to mention that T1 is derived from a long process and expected to be a small table whereas T2 is massive, and impossible to operate on without indexes

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood the explanation (possible) but the explanation, dummy values and expected results don't match up for me.

Comment: Native SQL is a techno (SAP related), a pseudo-name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because f2 and f3 are the same thing, you join between the two fields.

```
select f1 
from t1 
    left join t2 
        on t1.f2 = t2.f3 
        and t2.f4=2
where f3 is null
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what f3 is null does ? Haven't you joined all the unwanted scenarios ?

Comment: because it is a left (outer) join, it matches all entries in t1, and the `where .. is null` removes those where there is a match.

Comment: Would this query not return (2) , (3) , (4) as well as T2 entry (1,1) is a match for f1 = 2,3,4

Comment: The left join alone would return 1,2,3,4,5 from which the where clause removes 1 and 5 because they match to (1,2). Try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT F1
FROM T1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(F3) FROM T2 WHERE T1.F2 = T2.F3 AND T2.F4 = 2) = 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't this query have performance issues ? Is there an alternative to counting all, keeping in mind that all it takes is one.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN should be work for this. DISTINCT can be used to avoid duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT f1
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.f2 = T2.f3
WHERE T2.f4 IS NULL OR T2.f4 <> 2
```